# How to make a text and image fadein and fadeout as slidshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a slidshow and I want to add a text to the image that are fading in and fading out.I want the text to fade in and out with the concerned image.The text and the image are appearing but the problem is that the they are not appear as slidshow .I'm Working on this for 3 days now and i can not find out why it does not work .if you can help with it you are  making my day I have given the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <style>body, html {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90px;
        font-family: Poiret One;
        height: 100%;
        color: black;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: black;
    }
 
    .letter {
        position: relative;
        top: -webkit-calc(50% - 60px);
        top: calc(50% - 60px);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 200ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 200ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 400ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 400ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 600ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 600ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(4) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 800ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 800ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1000ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1000ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(6) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1200ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1200ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(7) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1400ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1400ms;
    }
 
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        50% {
            opacity: 0.02;
        }
    }
 
    @keyframes fade {
        50% {
            opacity: 0.02;
        }
    }</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
<span class='letter'>T</span>
<span class='letter'>E</span>
<span class='letter'>S</span>

<span class='letter'>T <img class="w3-animate-fading" src="https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/750x428p/cpi.studiod.com/www_ehow_com/i.ehow.com/images/a06/3a/be/study-compass-math-placement-test-800x800.jpg" style="width:50%;"></span>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
<span class='letter'>T</span>
<span class='letter'>E</span>
<span class='letter'>S</span>
<span class='letter'>S</span>
<span class='letter'>2 <img class="w3-animate-fading" src="https://insurancemarket.ng/images/thumbnails/280/95/detailed/3/26e178f.png" style="width:50%;"></span>
 


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want Test1 to appear first, followed by Test2?

Comment: Yes like a slidshow

Comment: Can you show us an example of a slide show you are trying to replicate? For some reason I don't think you're trying to make a slideshow like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: @MichaelSorensen Thank you for taking your time to write me .
I'm trying to create something like this but https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr   i want to my next to be next to it and fade in and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I couldn't exactly do this with CSS since I am terrible at CSS animation, so I decided to do it with jQuery!

```js
$("div").hide();
blank();
function blank() {
$(".1").fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
$(".2").delay(2800).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
$(".3").delay(5600).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
$(".4").delay(8400).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
setTimeout(blank, 11200);
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left:250px;
  margin-top:150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div 1">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amat.</div>
<div class="div 2">Quod Est Super Omne Nomem.</div>
<div class="div 3">Exaltabunt Sancti in Gloria.</div>
<div class="div 4">Ubi Caritas et amor, Christus.</div>
```

in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uod0hp6L/32/

So for me the `.fadeOut();` and `.fadeIn();` are set to 400, or .4 seconds. To get a clean look, you could add that. The `.delay();` just keeps it on the screen before fading out. So for the first one its `$("#first").fadeIn(time1).delay(time2).fadeOut(time3);` where "time" is measured in ms.
Then for the second one: `$("#second").delay(time1+time2+time3).fadeIn(time1).delay(time2).fadeOut(time3);`
Then the delay at the beginning gets doubled(of time1+time2+time3)for the third one, trippled(time1+time2+time3) for the fourth one, etc. For the last `setTimeout(function, x*(time1+time2+time3));` where x is num of .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() functions + 1. So for me, there were four fadeIn(); and fadeOut(); functions, so 4+1=5, and 5*2800=11200.

Just replace your own css and ids and/or classes into the jquery and modify the html and you got yourself one!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answer my question.what you did its cool